# Calling a Linux command via java.lang.Runtime.exec

Tags: java, linux

This is my code in Java:

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process p = rt.exec("nohup java -jar /root/xxxx.jar &");
```

This command can be executed, I can see that the service is started, but I have not seen the nohup log, why is this?

Comment: If you read the javadoc for [Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) that seems like it's a wrapper around the C lib exec - i.e. it's not got a shell that's processing what you wrote.

Comment: For reference [linux exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Comment: Correct.  If you want to run a shell command line that uses shell built-in command, shell argument expansion, globbing, redirection, etcetera, you need to run the command in a shell; e.g. by effectively using `Runtime.exec` to run something like `/bin/sh -c "your command line"`.   But this question has been asked many, many times before.

Comment: @StephenC this Q seems not to be duplicate. In this particular case `nohup` wrapper has no effect because processes spawned via `java.lang.Runtime#exec` are not bound to `tty`, so if TC is actually asking about how to properly "daemonize" spawned application the answer  like "use `sh -c ...`" won't help much.

Comment: In that case, if the purpose of this is to capture the output, then `nohup` won't work at all.   But unless you use a `/bin/sh -c` or something, the `&` will be treated as a command argument for the `java` command.   And the command won't be backgrounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short story**

Your expectations are based on observations which are actually irrelevant to java, basically that ("redirecting output to `nohup.out`") does not work because processes spawned via `java.lang.Runtime#exec` are not bound to `tty`, thus `nohup` `wrapper` has no effect.

**Long story**

**Q**: Why do `UNIX` guys need to use `nohup` `wrapper` when they want to spawn long-running process/program?

When we are working from `shell` it's first three file descriptors (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) are bound to `tty`, for example:

```
]# ls -la /proc/self/fd/[0-2]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:29 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:29 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:29 /proc/self/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/2
```

and any process spawned from `shell` inherits those three file descriptors, for example:

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

...

# another shell
# 65681 - pid of ping
# 65654 - pid of shell (parent)

]# ps -ef | grep ping
root     65681 65654  0 09:31 pts/2    00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
root     65700 65684  0 09:32 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ping
]# ls -la /proc/65681/fd/[0-2]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:32 /proc/65681/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:32 /proc/65681/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:32 /proc/65681/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/2
```

**Q**: what will happen if we leave our `shell`?

```
]# kill -9 65654
]# ls -la /proc/65681/fd/[0-2]
ls: cannot access /proc/65681/fd/[0-2]: No such file or directory
]# ps -ef | grep 65681
root     65738 65684  0 09:40 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 65681
```

Operating system was need to close `tty` (we left `shell`), so `OS` sends `SIGHUP` signal to all processes which was using (bound to) that `tty` and closes `tty`

The purpose of `nohup` `wrapper` is following:

it inspects whether first three file descriptors (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) are bound to `tty` and if so it replaces them by `/dev/null`, `nohup.out` and `nohup.out`:

```
]# nohup ping 8.8.8.8
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

...

# another shell
# 65767 - pid of ping
# 65752 - pid of shell (parent)

]# ps -ef | grep ping
root     65767 65752  0 09:44 pts/2    00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
root     65773 65684  0 09:45 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ping
]# ls -la /proc/65767/fd/[0-2]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:45 /proc/65767/fd/0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:45 /proc/65767/fd/1 -> /nohup.out
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:45 /proc/65767/fd/2 -> /nohup.out
```

now, trying to "leave" our `shell`:

```
]# kill -9 65752
]# ls -la /proc/65767/fd/[0-2]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:45 /proc/65767/fd/0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:45 /proc/65767/fd/1 -> /nohup.out
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:45 /proc/65767/fd/2 -> /nohup.out
]# ps -ef | grep ping
root     65767     1  0 09:44 ?        00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
root     65781 65684  0 09:46 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ping
```

our long-running application is continuing running, everyone is happy - that is `nohup` `wrapper` magic.

In regard to your Q...

If your goal it to re-implement the same using `Java` you need to do the same in `Java` and do not rely on `nohup` `wrapper`, below are some examples:

Let's try using "naive" implementation like:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.exec("ping 8.8.8.8");
        Thread.sleep(1_000_000_000);
    }
    
}
```

```
]# $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac Test.java 
]# $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp . Test 

# another shell
# 65890 - pid of ping
# 65873 - pid of java (parent)

]# ps -ef | grep ping
root     65890 65873  0 09:58 pts/2    00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
root     65895 65684  0 09:59 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ping
]# ls -la /proc/65890/fd/[0-2]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:58 /proc/65890/fd/0 -> pipe:[651007]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:58 /proc/65890/fd/1 -> pipe:[651008]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 09:58 /proc/65890/fd/2 -> pipe:[651009]
```

now, instead of seeing file descriptors like "/dev/pts/xxx" we are seeing something weird like `pipe:[xxx]`. What is that? That is `UNIX IPC` - child process sends data to parent process via [anonymous pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe). Anonymous pipes are not `tty`s, and that is why `nohup` `wrapper` won't have any effect, we may demonstrate that using `shell` (neither "nohup.out" in output nor "ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'" message):

```
]# nohup ping 8.8.8.8 </dev/null 2>&1 | cat
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 nohup ping 8.8.8.8 < /dev/null 2>&1 | cat
]# ps -ef | grep ping
root     66840 65684  0 12:38 pts/3    00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
root     66845 65684  0 12:38 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ping
]# ls -la /proc/66840/fd/[0-2]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 12:38 /proc/66840/fd/0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 12:38 /proc/66840/fd/1 -> pipe:[659814]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 12:38 /proc/66840/fd/2 -> pipe:[659814]
```

What will happen if parent process gets exited? Actually, it depends on whether child process is sending data via [anonymous pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe) or not, but in the worst case child process will exit:

```
]# kill 65873
]# ls -la /proc/65890/fd/[0-2]
]# ps -ef | grep ping
root     66238 65684  0 10:31 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ping
```

And the only reliable way to get the behaviour similar to `nohup` `wrapper` is to "re-implement" `nohup` `wrapper` on Java side:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("ping", "8.8.8.8")
                .directory(new File("/tmp"))
                .redirectInput(new File("/dev/null"))
                .redirectOutput(new File("/tmp/nohup.out"))
                .redirectError(new File("/tmp/nohup.out"))
                .start();
        Thread.sleep(1_000_000_000);
    }

}
```

```
]# ps -ef | grep ping
root     66394 66377  0 10:37 pts/2    00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
root     66398 65684  0 10:37 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ping
]# kill 66377
]# ls -la /proc/66394/fd/[0-2]
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 10:37 /proc/66394/fd/0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 10:37 /proc/66394/fd/1 -> /tmp/nohup.out
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Aug 20 10:37 /proc/66394/fd/2 -> /tmp/nohup.out
]# ps -ef | grep 66394
root     66394     1  0 10:37 pts/2    00:00:00 ping 8.8.8.8
root     66402 65684  0 10:38 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 66394
```

Thus, the java implementation of yours:

```
nohup java -jar /root/xxxx.jar &
```

is:

```java
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "/root/xxxx.jar")
        .redirectInput(new File("/dev/null"))
        .redirectOutput(new File("nohup.out"))
        .redirectError(new File("nohup.out"))
        .start();
```